# Ubuntu 19.04 new install stuck at boot starting hostname service

Tags: boot, nvidia

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my computer and on the first boot it gets stuck at starting hostname service every boot it does this it will not boot up into Ubuntu. I tried the recovery mode and let it check for packages to fix through dkpg and this does not solve the problem either.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem or what causes this problem?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what nvidia card do you have?  I'm suspecting rtx super? anything older should be supported by the nvidia driver 418 that are installed if you check the box to install restricted drivers.  Or did you install nvidia drivers by donwloading them from nvidia?

Comment: @TrailRider I have same problem with 2060 rtx . How can I solve it ?

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Comment: Got the same issue, running an RTX 3070

Answer (score 2):

I am on a system with an nVidia card as well. I am not sure your problem is the same as mine, but in order for me to be able to boot, I had to add `nomodeset` to the kernel line in the GRUB menu entry.

When the GRUB boot menu is shown, press `e` to edit the menu entry. Go to the line that starts with `linux` & add `nomodeset` to the list of options then press `F10` to boot. More details are in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/368629).

If that boots your system correctly, make the change permanent by editing `/etc/default/grub` & adding `nomodeset` to the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

For example, change the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub`.

I also had booting issues when I tried using the nVidia proprietary drivers. I recommend using the open source `nouveau` driver if you are still having problems after adding `nomodeset` to GRUB. You may be able to change the driver by dropping to a root shell from recovery mode.

```
# apt purge xserver-xorg-video-nvidia*

# apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```